# If hidden form contains input with id='style', it won't be visible after setting display='block' in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following code:

```html
<form id='f' style='display: none'>
 <input type='text' id='style'/>
</form>

<button onclick='document.getElementById("f").style.display = "block"'>Click</button>
```

After clicking on the button, I would expect the form to become visible, but it doesn't. Why is that?

Note that if one of the following conditions is true it works as expected:

- input id is not named "style"
- another tag such as div is used instead of form
- a non form element tag is used instead of input (i.e. tags such as p or div work fine; input, textarea and button don't)

Comment: That's not right @AhsN -- its because the input id is `style`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control elements inside a form become properties of form element also. So you are making the `style` property of the `<form>` reference an input by using `style` as it's id.

If you add `console.log(document.getElementById('f').style)` it will return  `<input id="style">` instead of the expected style rules of the element

I would wrap the form in a container and apply inline style to that container instead. It's rare that you would use a `<form>` as a block element

```html
<div id="f" style='display: none'>
  <form>
    <input type='text' id='style' />
  </form>
</div>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("f").style.display = "block"'>Click</button>
```

Comment: "Control elements become properties of form also" - this is true but how/where we can find that information?

Answer (score 1):

It's because by using 'id='style' in the child element you are creating a reference to that child instead of accessing the style of the parent, in order to fix that you should use a different name for the id.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kwz3v9fx/2/

```html
<form id='f' style='display: none'>
  <input type='text' id='anotherName'/>
</form>
    
<button onclick='document.getElementById("f").style.display = "block"'>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because inline style (`style="display: none;"`) has priority over your internal style (`document.getElementById("f").style.display = "block"`). To fix this, use `setAttribute` instead:

```html
<form id='f' style='display: none'>
 <input type='text' id='style'/>
</form>

<button onclick='document.getElementById("f").setAttribute("style", "display: block;")'>Click</button>
```

You can see why this is because `<form>` elements are treated as objects in JavaScript, and when the child elements have either a `name` or `id` property, that is added as a property to the `form` object. See the snippet below:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("f").style); 
/*This shows the <input> element rather than the styles 
applied to the actual <form> element*/
```

```html
<form id="f">
    <input type="text" id="style" />
</form>
```

Comment: Solution works (although counter-intuitive) but explanation of why is wrong. `console.log(document.getElementById('f').style)` will show you why